# Posicionamento de widget kivy

Tags: python-kivy

Estou apanhando dos gerenciadores de Layout mas estou avançando aos poucos.

Tenho esse código de estudo:

```
<Tela@RelativeLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,1,.05
        Rectangle:
            pos: [0.2*coord for coord in self.size]
            size: [0.6*coord for coord in self.size]

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: .5,.5
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb:.5,.3,.3
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Button:
            text: 'B5'
```

Que me da como resultado a seguinte tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque o B5 não fica no centro como o GridLayout já que e filho dele?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

você precisa definir relativo ao que "B5" irá se posicionar, logo você precisar definir 'pos' de B5 como pos: `self.x + 100, self.y + 100` por exemplo que será 100 pixels "para dentro" de GridLayout